# Issue with image size displayed while using angular material grid list

Tags: angularjs, image, angular-material, grid-layout

I'm trying to generate the grid view shown below using angular...[image: Grid layout]

Here's my HTML

```
<md-content layout-padding>
        <md-grid-list
                md-cols-gt-md="3" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="3" md-cols-xs="1"
                md-row-height-gt-sm="1:1" md-row-height="4:3"
                md-gutter-gt-md="16px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px" md-gutter="4px">
            <md-grid-tile
                    ng-repeat="tile in sc.grid track by $index"
                    ng-style="{
        'border': '1px solid grey'
      }"
                    md-colspan-gt-sm="{{tile.colspan}}"
                    md-rowspan-gt-sm="{{tile.rowspan}}">
                    <img proxy="{{sc.panelInfo[$index].img}}"/>
                    <md-grid-tile-footer><h3>{{sc.panelInfo[$index].title}}</h3></md-grid-tile-footer>

            </md-grid-tile>
        </md-grid-list>
    </md-content>
```

Controller code:

```
        self.grid = (function() {
        var tiles = [];
        var colspan = [2,1,1,1,3];
        var rowspan = [1,2,1,1,1];
        var width = [600,300,300,300,940];
        var height = [275,600,275,275,275];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            tiles.push({
                colspan: colspan[i],
                rowspan: rowspan[i],
                width: width[i],
                height:height[i]
            });
        }
        return tiles;
    })();
```

I'm able to get the images displayed but they all show up as square images and overlap even though the dimensions are different. The image in the first tile shows up as 600x 600 even though it is only 600 x 275. The second tile is truncated and shows up as 300x 300 instead of 300 x 600. Please help.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. It was the image proxy that was causing the issue. Changed it to image src and it works!